# failed to compile fragment shader when using tensorflow on Angular

Tags: angular, tensorflow.js

I am trying to implement transfer learning on an angular application. For the collection of new data, I thought I'll just use the exact same code from the tutorial on tensorflow js, the one used on the pacman game.

This is the code of the controller_dataset.js from the tensorflow.js tutorial. I imported this on a component on angular.

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';


export class ControllerDataset {
    constructor(numClasses) {
      this.numClasses = numClasses;
    }


   addExample(example, label) {

    const y = tf.tidy(() => tf.oneHot(tf.tensor1d([label]).toInt(), this.numClasses));

    if (this.xs == null) {
      this.xs = tf.keep(example);
      this.ys = tf.keep(y);
    } else {
      const oldX = this.xs;
      this.xs = tf.keep(oldX.concat(example, 0));

      const oldY = this.ys;
      this.ys = tf.keep(oldY.concat(y, 0));

      oldX.dispose();
      oldY.dispose();
      y.dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when the controller.addExample is called it results in the following error

```
ERROR Error: Failed to compile fragment shader.
at createFragmentShader (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at e.createProgram (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at compileProgram (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at tf-core.esm.js:17
at e.getAndSaveBinary (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at e.compileAndRun (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at e.oneHot (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at ENV.engine.runKernel.indices (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at e.runKernel (tf-core.esm.js:17)
at e.oneHot (tf-core.esm.js:17)
```

Comment: Did you try running it with a different tfjs version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error comes from using `this.numClasses`. In the constructor of your class, you passed in the parameter `numClasses`. But when your component is being called, there is no argument numClasses defined. As result, `this.numClasses` will be undefined.

Consider assigning to `this.numClasses` a value

```js
 addExample(example, label) {

    // set this.numClasses with a value 
    const y = tf.tidy(() => tf.oneHot(tf.tensor1d([label]).toInt(), this.numClasses));

 }
```

Comment: Turns out I left the variable for my numClasses undefined